# Is it possible to get a collection of different model types for a model using eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

If I have a model that needs to have a property that is an array of different models. Is there an eloquent method or way to handle this kind of problem?

eg.
I have a **Feature** model that needs a method that gets an array of objects that are from different models.

```
class Feature extends Model
{

    public function getArrayOfDifferentObjects()
    {
        $array_of_objects=array();

        ???? ELOQUENT to get objects from different models ????

        return $array_of_objects;
    }

}
```

I have a **feature_model_connections** table with the following:

- feature_id
- featured_model_id
- featured_model_type

The featured_model_type value would be a string denoting the model type. 
The model_id would be a foreign key of the relevant model's table.

However I can't see how you would be able to use eloquent to return data for the getArrayOfDifferentObjects method in features model.

Any pointers would be much appreciated. Many thanks, J

Comment: Can you add an example of one of those related models, and any relevant relationships that have been defined?

Comment: Did my solution help you, or do you have any problems still?

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing there, is basicly a `Polymorphic Relations`, which can handle these cases, and making fetching them easy, instead of i'm making a made up case, read the documentation, it is well written, under the section `Polymorphic Relations`. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Within your scope right now, you can do something like this.

```
public function getArrayOfDifferentObjects()
{
    $objects = [];

    $features = DB::table('feature_model_connections')
              ->select('feature_id', 'featured_model_id', 'featured_model_type')->get();

    foreach($features as $feature)
    {
        $type = '\\App\\' . $feature->featured_model_type; //App is you app namespace

        $model = $type::find($feature->featured_model_id);

        if($model)
            $objects[] = $model;
    }

    return $objects;
}
```

The basics of this, is you can define different `types`, with the `app` `namespace` seed, from there staticly call them, which will access the predefined type in your database table, then find the `element` and add it to the `array`. With that said, this is done as of the top of my head, no compile check, not ranned in `Laravel`, but it should pretty much get you the idea of what to do, with that said, if you can change your structure, go with the `Polymorphic Relations`, it is really awesome.

Comment: Hey @Martin Henriksen, thanks for your response and apologies for the delay in my reply. I had looked at the polymorphic relations as suggested and have been able to piece together a solution. I imagine that the main advantage using the morphTo method rather than your above solution is that it also takes advantage of eager loading?.. are there any other reasons not to just do as you have proposed? (Thanks again)

Comment: Yes, you can utilize eager loading. In my subjective opinion, in the team i work in, we prefer to utilize Laravel functionality, if it exists instead of brewing up your own. This is for understanding and maintainability, meanwhile you are developing Laravel and should stride to do it the  Laravel way, meanwhile you are now letting the Laravel guys handling the implementation instead of you, meaning that if you are trying to do something fancy with the relations Laravel is gonna throw Exceptions and similar.